# How important are Frege works to an analytic philosopher?

Tags: philosophy-of-language, linguistics, frege

Don't kill me. I know he is a big deal.

But I am starting out in analytic philosophy and I am not quite sure how deep I should go in a first approach. Should I read all the context and other writings or an introduction, read other authors and then come back?

Thanks

Comment: Fundamental. See e.g. [M.Dummett's Origins of analytical philosophy](https://books.google.it/books?id=6wjZAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) as well as [Dummett's volumes on Frege](https://www.google.it/search?tbm=bks&hl=it&q=dummett+frege&safe=active).

Comment: It depends on what kind of analytic philosophy you are interested in. Frege did not consider himself an analytic philosopher (the term originates with Russell and Moore) and was only later linked to it, largely due to Dummett's efforts. There are large parts of what is now called "analytic philosophy" (e.g. analytic pragmatism) that are not centered on analysis of concepts and language (the origin of the term) and owe more to Kant than to Frege, see [IEP's Analytic Philosophy](https://www.iep.utm.edu/analytic).

Answer (score 1):

Depends on waht you're looking for. You could read him for logic, phil. of mathematics or phil. of language.

> I am starting out in analytic philosophy

Because of this I'll assume it's the latter. I recommend getting context on two things. 1) Read up on criticism of psychologism. This should give you an idea what Frege aims at. It should also give you possible approaches to the relation between Husserl and Frege, where they diverge etc. 2) Get an overview of Ideal Language Philosophy.

For phil. of language you'll have to read at least *Sense and Reference* and *The Thought*.

As for Dummett's stuff, some consider it misleading if you want an accurate historical representation. But it can stand on its own.

Relevant SEP articles you might want to check:

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege
https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/psychologism/#FreAntArg
https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/reference/